# Calculation with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hi guys I have this Dataframe in R:

```
m2 <- c(22,NA,0,NA,42,NA)
m3 <- c(89,38,0,67,0,NA)
df = data.frame(m2,m3)
```

I want to calculate the return between m3 and m2. The formular is: return = (m2[i] - m3[i])/m3[i]. Conditions to calculate is:

1. if m2[i] = NA or m3[i] = NA then the result = NA
2. if m2[i] = 0 and m3[i] = 0 then the result = -9999
3. if m2[i] != 0 and m3[i] = 0 then the result = 9999

So far I have tried these code:

```
   for (i in nrow(df)){
      if (is.na(df[['m2']][i]) == TRUE | is.na(df[['m3']][i]) == TRUE){df[['result']][i] = NA}
      if (df[['m2']][i] == 0 & df[['m3']][i] == 0) {df[['result']][i] = 9999}
      if (df[['m3']][i] == 0 | df[['m2']][i] != 0) {df[['result']][i] = -9999}
      else {df[['result']][i] = (df[['m2']][i] - df[['m3']][i])/df[['m3']][i]}
    }
```

But it returns as shown below:

```
 Error in if (df[["m2"]][i] == 0 & df[["m3"]][i] == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE need
```

I have tried the same method for python and it works. Is there any way to do it in R and should I calculate the returns without using for loop?

Comment: You can use a nested `ifelse` without needing to loop, i.e. `ifelse(is.na(df$m2)|is.na(df$m3), NA, ifelse(df$m2 == 0 & df$m3 == 0, 9999, ifelse(df$m3 == 0 & df$m2 != 0, -9999, (df$m2 - df$m3)/df$m3)))
[1]    -0.752809           NA  9999.000000           NA -9999.000000           NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want readability, `case_when` from `dplyr` could be an option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    result = case_when(
      is.na(m2) | is.na(m3) ~ NA_real_,
      m2 == 0 & m3 == 0 ~ 9999,
      m2 != 0 & m3 == 0 ~ -9999,
      TRUE ~ (m2 - m3) / m3
    )
  )
```

As @markus added, you could indeed skip the first line to get the same output.

I'd also suggest to read `?case_when` help page to get acquainted with some specifics (such as the relevance of order, skipping `TRUE`, why using `NA_real_` in the above case, etc.).

Comment: You could save the first line because if either `m2` or `m3` is `NA` the result of `(m2 - m3) / m3` will be `NA` too.

Comment: Thanks @markus! Since OP probably doesn't know about `case_when` I wanted it to be transparent, but in everyday life this would likely be skipped indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I would break this two steps:

```r
m2 <- c(22,NA,0,NA,42,NA)
m3 <- c(89,38,0,67,0,NA)
df = data.frame(m2,m3)


df$return <- with(df, (m2 - m3)/m3)
df$return <- with(df, ifelse(m2 == 0 & m3 == 0, -9999, ifelse(m2 != 0 & m3 == 0, 9999, return)))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The things to note here include 1) use `ifelse()` since it is vectorized (i.e. will operate on all rows of df naturally, avoiding having to code a for loop, and 2) R will naturally yield `NA` if `m2` or `m3` are `NA`, so you can just spell out the conditions for when `return` should equal `9999` or `-9999`.

Answer (score 1):

```
m2 <- c(22,NA,0,NA,42,NA)
m3 <- c(89,38,0,67,0,NA)
df = data.frame(m2,m3)


library(tidyverse)

df %>%  mutate( return = ifelse(is.na(df$m2)|is.na(df$m3), NA, ifelse(df$m2 == 0 & df$m3 == 0, 9999, ifelse(df$m3 == 0 & df$m2 != 0, -9999, (df$m2 - df$m3)/df$m3))) )
```

Answer (score 1):

What your logic really is stating is that you want to change:

```
NaN to -9999 (occurs for 0/0)
Inf to 9999 (occurs for x/0)
```

So you can simply apply your formula and then substitute later. It just seems a little less convoluted to me to look at. I avoid 'if-then' logic whenever possible.

**base R solution:**

```
df$return <- (df$m2 - df$m3) / df$m3
df[is.nan(df$return),"return"] <- -9999
df[is.infinite(df$return),"return"] <- 9999
```

**dplyr solution:**

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(return = (m2 - m3) / m3,
         return = if_else(is.nan(return), -9999, return),
         return = if_else(is.infinite(return), 9999, return))
```